# How to do a dictionary kind of search in SharePoint online

Tags: search

Is it possible to implement a search in SharePoint online with dictionary words?
Eg. If I am searching for Cherry word, it should return me Cherries as well. 
Results should contain Cherry and Cherries both words.

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as Stemming and SharePoint and SharePoint Online do this by default to a limited degree. If you wish to enhance the support for stemming based on the content in your environment I would build and maintain a thesaurus file. This can then be uploaded with PowerShell for SharePoint on-prem, but is not supported in SPO...yet.

Comment: Can you please provide me some help link to do that?

Comment: The Thesaurus is not available in SPO so you have to use one of a few clever workarounds. Elio has a few good ideas that I have used in the past: https://www.eliostruyf.com/a-better-way-for-search-synonyms-in-sharepoint-online-2013-2016/